# How to add user-resizable images in a textbox for Python GUI

Tags: python, image, user-interface, textbox, resize

I'm trying to make a word processor type program in python. I'd like the user to be able to open a resizable image into the text area like in MS Word. I've looked into wxpython and tkinter. My understanding is that wxpython doesn't have a feature for images inside textboxes, and I'm not sure if tkinter has a way of letting the user resize the image. Is there a way for me to add this feature using one of the popular GUI toolkits?

Comment: I think PyQt may be your choice.

Answer (score 1):

Use [PyQt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyQt). You can achieve lot of things through the highly capable library offered by them.

Another option is to use [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/).

Both toolkit also offer GUI building tools for ease of creation.